# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ParseStarterProject:classpath'

Tags: android, parse-platform

I went to updated to the latest Android Studio and now when I go to build I get the below error. I have no idea what's going on, and no clue how to do the whole --stacktrace thing it says if that will help me at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   Executing tasks: [:ParseStarterProject:clean, :ParseStarterProject:generateDebugSources, :ParseStarterProject:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :ParseStarterProject:mockableAndroidJar, :ParseStarterProject:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :ParseStarterProject:assembleDebug]

    Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':ParseStarterProject'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ParseStarterProject:classpath'.
       > Could not resolve com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+.
         Required by:
             Archive 2 2:ParseStarterProject:unspecified
          > Could not resolve com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+.
             > Failed to list versions for com.parse.tools:gradle.
                > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.parse.com/repo/com/parse/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
                   > Could not GET 'https://maven.parse.com/repo/com/parse/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
                      > peer not authenticated

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 2.256 secs
```

Here are my gradle files

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

2.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "22"

    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 22
}
```

Comment: Yes exact same issue.

Comment: Can you show your gradle files

Comment: Added them for you

Answer (score 2):

The issue was reported here:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/463

Parse may have stopped "hosting their Gradle plugin". So remove

```
maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
```

from 'repositories' and

```
classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
```

from 'dependencies'

Comment: Wouldn't removing "maven...etc..." from 'repositories' and "classpath...etc..." from 'dependencies stop Parse functionality?   Or is just Parse's crash reporting affected by these removals?

Comment: In this case it would just remove crash reporting since the OP already has the Parse library in their 'dependencies' from "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')"

Answer (score 2):

Remove:

1. apply plugin: 'com.parse'
2. classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
3. maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }

And re-build project. Everything should work fine.